How can I invert `dataclass.astuple`?
I am trying to construct a hierarchy of dataclasses from a tuple, like so:
from dataclasses import astuple, dataclass

@dataclass
class Child:
    name: str

@dataclass
class Parent:
    child: Child

# this is what I want
p = Parent(Child("Tim"))
print(p)

# this is what I get
t = astuple(p)
print(Parent(*t))

However, while this constructs a Parent as expected, its child is not of type Child:
Parent(child=Child(name='Tim'))
Parent(child=('Tim',))

Is there a way to construct Parent and child from the tuple t, or by some other means?

You can use a helper function that constructs an instance of a dataclass from a given tuple of values and recursively constructs child instances for fields that are dataclasses:
from dataclasses import astuple, dataclass, fields, is_dataclass

@dataclass
class Child:
    name: str

@dataclass
class Parent:
    child: Child

def from_tuple(cls, data):
    return cls(*(
        from_tuple(type, obj) if is_dataclass(type := field.type) else obj
        for obj, field in zip(data, fields(cls))
    ))

p = Parent(Child("Tim"))
t = astuple(p)
print(from_tuple(Parent, t))

This outputs:
Parent(child=Child(name='Tim'))

Demo here

One solution that I have found is
from dataclasses import astuple, dataclass

@dataclass
class Child:
    name: str

@dataclass
class Parent:
    child: Child

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        if isinstance(self.child, tuple):
            self.child = Child(*self.child)

# this is what I want
p = Parent(Child("Tim"))
print(p)

# this is what I get
t = astuple(p)
print(Parent(*t))

Type-checkers don't like it too much since they insist everything done in __post_init__ is either invalid or unncessary, but it does work at runtime.
This can be fixed, too:
from dataclasses import astuple, dataclass
from typing import Any, cast

@dataclass
class Child:
    name: str

@dataclass
class Parent:
    child: Child

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        child = cast(Any, self.child)
        if isinstance(child, tuple):
            self.child = Child(*child)

# this is what I want
p = Parent(Child("Tim"))
print(p)

# this is what I get
t = astuple(p)
print(Parent(*t))

Output of both:
Parent(child=Child(name='Tim'))
Parent(child=Child(name='Tim'))

